# My SQLite query causes a cursorindexoutofbounds exception when the column in the WHERE clause is empty. How do I stop this?

Tags: java, android, cursor

This error only occurs when the column COLUMN_NAME_DATE is empty (no entries have been made in that table).  Once I add some entries, it works fine.  I have tried all sorts of null checks, and what not, but nothing is working.  The error exactly:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, 
 with a size of 0
```

Here is the faulty code:

```
    if (cursor1.moveToFirst() == false) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No categories found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {

        for (int i = cursor1.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            catTotal = 0;
            cursor1.moveToPosition(i);
            curCat = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                    CategoriesDbContract.TblCategories.COLUMN_NAME_CATEGORY));

            cursor2 = db.query(TransactionsDbContract.TblTransactions.TABLE_NAME,
                           null, 
                           TransactionsDbContract.TblTransactions.COLUMN_NAME_DATE + ">" + dateSent, 
                           null, null, null, null);

            for (int j = cursor2.getCount() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                cursor2.moveToPosition(j);
                catTotal += cursor2.getDouble(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                        TransactionsDbContract.TblTransactions.COLUMN_NAME_AMOUNT));
            }

            percent = catTotal/overallTotal * 100;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
            df.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
            String percStr = df.format(percent);

            category += cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                    CategoriesDbContract.TblCategories.COLUMN_NAME_CATEGORY)) + "\n";

            spent += percStr + "\n";
        }
```

Comment: You have done a lot of work to loop backwards through your Cursors.  I recommend simply using the OrderBy parameter / clause to reverse the results for you and use `while(cursor.moveToNext())` _or_ you could call `moveToLast()` and `while(cursor.moveToPrevious())`.  That said, which line through the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that your error is here:

```
for (int j = cursor2.getCount() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    cursor2.moveToPosition(j); // j might be -1
```

... because if your statement ...

```
cursor2 = db.query(TransactionsDbContract.TblTransactions.TABLE_NAME, ...);
```

... returns no rows, `cursor2.getCount()` is zero and so `j` starts with `-1`.

I would propose that you use ...

```
while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
    catTotal = 0;
    curCat = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                     CategoriesDbContract.TblCategories.COLUMN_NAME_CATEGORY));
    cursor2 = db.query(...);

    while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
        catTotal += cursor2.getDouble(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                        TransactionsDbContract.TblTransactions.COLUMN_NAME_AMOUNT));
    }
}
```

... because this way you don't need the `for` loops.

Hope this helps ... Cheers!

Comment: If `j == -1` then `j >= 0` fails and the program never enters the loop.  The termination expression is evaluated before the first iteration.  (Obviously, I agree with using `moveToNext()`. It's simpler.)